# Java server socket programming: How to send a message to all other clients besides the one that sent it

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a chat program that connects multiple clients to one server, and the server needs the ability to distribute received messages (utf-8 strings) to all other clients besides the one that sent the message.  I have a list of clients (with a position in the arraylist for each one). All clients connect to the server on same port.

Command line arguments for server/client to run

```
java ChatServer 1234
java ChatClient 1234
```

Here the code that I currently have in order to send a received message back to all other clients besides the one that sent it (currently does not work)

(the code below is within a class called ChatServer)(it is a prototype, not the correct/best solution, I just am using this as the first rough draft idea I had and will probably change it when I learn how to distribute received messages correctly)

```
//create variables to keep track of position
int position = 0;

int max = ListOfClients.size();

//create for loop to search through list of clients
for(int j = 0; j < max; j++)
{
   //This if-statment is what I want to change to make it work. 
   //How would I code "if(this client is not the original one that sent me a message
   if(j != 0 && j < max)
   {
      //send message to all other clients besides the one that sent it
      max++;
      OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
      bw.write(relayMessage + "\n");
      System.out.println("Message relayed to client: "+ relayMessage);
      bw.flush();   
      j=j-1;

   }
}
```

Server Code (ChatServer.java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatServer
{

    private static Socket socket;
    static //create a list of clients
    ArrayList<Socket> ListOfClients = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean KeepRunning = true;
        Thread Listening = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                    int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                    System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                    //SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(address, port_number1);
                    System.out.println( "Listening for connections on port: " + ( port_number1 ) );
                    boolean KeepRunning = true;
                    while(KeepRunning)
                    {

                        //Connect to the client
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        //ListOfClients.add(socket);
                        Thread RecievingAndSending = new Thread()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if(socket!=null)
                                    {
                                        ListOfClients.add(socket);
                                        //ChatServer client = new ChatServer();
                                        //client.setUniqueId(uniqueID);
                                        //int listsize = ListOfClients.size();
                                        //UUID uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID(); 
                                        //System.out.println("This client's id is"+ uniqueID);

                                        //reading message form client
                                        BufferedReader BufReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));  
                                        String relayMessage = BufReader1.readLine();


                                        //relaying message to every other client besides the one it was from
                                        if(relayMessage == "" || relayMessage == null)
                                        {
                                            System.exit(0);

                                        }   
                                        else //this is where the question is
                                        {
                                            //int position = 0;
                                            //int max = ListOfClients.size();
                                            //for(int j = 0; j < max; j++)
                                            //{
                                                //if(j != 0 && j < max)
                                            //  {
                                                 // max++;
                                                  OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                                  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                                  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                                  bw.write(relayMessage + "\n");
                                                  System.out.println("Message relayed to client: "+ relayMessage);
                                                  bw.flush();   
                                                //  j=j-1;

                                                //}
                                            //}
                                        }


                                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                                            bw.flush();
                                    }

                                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        finally
                                        {

                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                                RecievingAndSending.start();

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {

                }

            }
        };
        Listening.start();

    }
}
```

[This is what it currently looks like when run (clients on left server on right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fci5X.png)

Client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatClient
{
    final int numberOfClients = 0;
    private static Socket socket;
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        ChatClient chatclient = new ChatClient();
        Object uniqueID = null;
        chatclient.setUniqueId(uniqueID);

                  String host = "localhost";
                  int numberOfClients = 0;
                  Thread ChatClient1 = new Thread ()
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {
                          boolean KeepRunning = true;
                          while(KeepRunning == true && args.length > 0)
                          {

                              try
                              {

                                  //Client begins, gets port number, listens, connects, prints out messages from other clients
                                  int port = 0;
                                  int port_1number1 = 0;
                                  int numberofmessages = 0;


                                  System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                                  System.out.println("Chat client is running");
                                  System.out.println("Port number is: " + args[0]);
                                  port = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                                  System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                                  System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + args[0] );
                                  // System.out.println(messagessentbyotherclients);

                                  socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                                  InetAddress inetlocalhost = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                                  SocketAddress localhost = new InetSocketAddress(inetlocalhost, port);
                                  //socket.connect(localhost, port);
                                  System.out.println("Client has connected");



                                  //client creates new message from standard input
                                  OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);



                                  //creating message to send from standard input
                                  String newmessage = "";
                                  try   
                                  {
                                      int k = 3;
                                      if(k==3)
                                      {
                                          // input the message from standard input encoded in UTF-8 string format
                                          BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                          String line = "";
                                          System.out.println( "Standard input (press enter then control D when finished): " );
                                          while( (line= input.readLine()) != null && k==3 )     
                                          {
                                              newmessage += line + " ";
                                              k=4;
                                          }
                                          k=6;
                                      }
                                  }
                                  catch ( Exception e )
                                  {
                                      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                                  }
                                  //Sending the message to server
                                  String sendMessage = newmessage;
                                  try 
                                  {
                                  //  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                                    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                                   // SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
                                    //OutputStream os1 = socket.getOutputStream();
                                    //OutputStreamWriter osw2 = new OutputStreamWriter(os1);
                                    //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw2);
                                    bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                                    bw.flush();
                                    //bw.close();
                                    //out.close();
                                    //os.close();

                                  } 
                                  catch (IOException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                  System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);

                                  //recieve messages from sever 
                                  //Get the return message from the server
                                  InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                                  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                                  String message = br.readLine();
                                  System.out.println("Message relayed from the server : " +message);

                              } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                              finally
                              {

                              }

                            //  KeepRunning = false;
                          }

                      }

                  };
                  ChatClient1.start();  
    }
    private void setUniqueId(Object uniqueID)
    {
        uniqueID = Math.random();

    }
}
```

My question is: How do I send a received message (as the server) to all clients within a list except for the original one that sent it?

Comment: Refactor, don't do everything in huge God-classes as you're doing. Myself, I'd not use a `List<Socket>` but rather would use a `List<HelperClass>` with the Helper class including all that's needed to communicate with it, including perhpas a unique String ID. This way you could get the ID of the connection that is sending the message, and send to all helpers that have a different ID.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I see. so  instead of ArrayList<Socket> ListOfClients = new ArrayList<Socket>(); I should use List<HelperClass> ListOfClients = new List<HelperClass>(); right?